# Mongo data modeling/updates for voting (up and down)

Tags: mongodb

There is an example on voting data model/update queries in Mongo:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+Data+Modeling+and+Rails#MongoDBDataModelingandRails-AtomicUpdates

However I need both up and down votes (basically, one person can either cast up vote or down vote). Also, I want for voter to be able to change his mind and change upvote to downvote or vice-versa (so the list of voters and total number does not fit).

What would be the best data model and corresponding update call?

I see two possibilities, either do a

```
'votes': [{ 'user_id' : ... , 'vote': ±1 }]
```

or

```
'upvoters': [...], 'downvoters': [...]
```

But I can't make an update query for the first one yet, and second one looks a bit weird (though it may be just me).

Comment: If I recall correctly, the example given in the MongoDB docs will allow -1 (not just plus 1) ... have you tried that? Or do you need to know the exact # of down vs. up votes?

Comment: Great comment. Yes, the reason is that I want to let person change their mind and cast a downvote where they cast an upvote before, and example in mongodb does not allow this. Added this to question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First schema looks like good. Second schema is hard because when user click upvote and than downvote you need add userId to 'upvoters' that to  'downvoters' and remove from 'upvoters' and vice versa.

I suppose votes it nestead collection of some document(suppose it questions).

```
db.questions.update({votes.userId: .. },{ $set : { votes.$.vote : 1 } });//upvote
db.questions.update({votes.userId: .. },{ $set : { votes.$.vote : -1 } });//down
```

And seems you need create extra field inside of questions collection to calculate sum of up/down votes:

```
db.questions.update({_id: .. },{ $inc : { votesCount : 1 } }); //up vote
db.questions.update({_id: .. },{ $inc : { votesCount : -1 } }); // down vote
```

If you need add new user to array of votes use

[Possitional operator.](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator)

Comment: It's worth noting that a decrementing by -1 for a user that has already placed an upvote will not result in a downvote and vice-versa regardless of which schema that the OP decides to go with.  That would be -2, or +2 respectively.

Comment: This update works if user is already in the collection, however it does not match if user is not. Should I do a $ne/$push command first?

Comment: Yes, sure first need to check that user exists or not, and that in user not exists $push otherwise update.

Comment: @ Anthony Jack: agree, but -2 and +2 also don't work. For example if you need votedown than need to check if user have voteup for some question than if voteup exists use {$inc: -2} else  {$inc: -1},   and {$inc: 2} else  {$inc: 1} for voteup

Comment: I think I will not need a count field yet, and the update itself works correctly with opinion changes, so I'll accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Seems much simpler to use the second schema.

```
Document:  { name: "name",
             upvoters: [name1, name2, etc],
             downvoters: [name1, name2, etc],
           }
```

To get total votes you can get the doc and use 
doc.upvoters.length-doc.downvoters.length
(start each document with upvoters and downvoters arrays being [ ])

To record any upvote by User "x" on item "c" just do:

```
db.votes.update({name:"c"},{$addToSet:{upvotes:"x"},$pull:{downvotes:"x"}})
```

This is atomic and it has advantage of doing the same thing even if you run it 10 times.
It also spares you from having to check if "x" already voted for "c" and which way.

To record downvote just reverse it:

```
db.votes.update({name:"c"},{$addToSet:{downvotes:"x"},$pull:{upvotes:"x"}})
```