# Automatic calculated fields

Tags: mongodb, automation, mongoose

Below is a Schema for my application. Under "meta" I have to fields that's called "upvotes" and "downvotes" and I want a field for the total amount of points (upvotes - downvotes). As for now I'm calculating this on the client side, but I also want to be able to sort by points (the image with most points first and descending).

Is there some way to auto calculate a field in Mongoose and if so, how is it done?

```
var ImageSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    size : Number,
    title   : String,
    body : String,
    buf : Buffer,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    comments : [CommentSchema],
    meta : {
        upvotes : Number,
        downvotes : Number,
        points : ? // <- upvotes - downvotes
        favs : Number,
        uniqueIPs : [String],
        tags : [String]
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a homework on this?  :)  I just answered a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035413/mongo-data-modeling-updates-for-voting-up-and-down - if you have a user who may change their vote from up to down, you may need to take care not to undercount the second vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make the `points` field a normal Number field, and increment (or decrement) it appropriately as you increment `upvotes` and `downvotes` (shown here using regular JS shell syntax, but the technique will work with mongoose as well):

```
// when upvoting
db.image.update({/* criteria */}, {$inc: {upvotes: 1, points: 1}})

// when downvoting
db.image.update({/* criteria */}, {$inc: {downvotes: 1, points: -1}})
```

If you have existing data, you'll need to generate the `points` field from the existing objects, but once you have it, it will be in sync due to the atomic nature of MongoDB updates and the `$inc` operator.

Comment: If unique IPs are supposed to track voters then this won't quite work when someone votes multiple times or changes their vote.  You can $addToSet and $pull for up/down votes but then you won't know whether to increment the votes (if they were already there)

Comment: I would include that in the "criteria" -- e.g., `...update({uniqueIps: {$ne: "1.2.3.4"}}, {$inc: {upvotes: 1, points: 1}, $push: {uniqueIps: "1.2.3.4"}})`

Answer (score 5):

You should use [Mongoose middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) :

```
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    // set points value based on positive and negatives 
})
```

This way, every time you save data, points value will be refreshed. The downside is that it will be refreshed even if down/upvotes aren't changed.

Warning : be extra carefull if several applications use the same DB, you want the same logic to be applied everywhere.